# C# Using and Compiling Windows.Form

Tags: c#, user-interface, reference, system.componentmodel

I am working on coding a GUI with C#. I'm following [this](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=27316) simple tutorial to get started. To compile, I need to reference System.Windows.Forms.DLL System.Drawing.DLL, so I type

```
csc /r:System.Windows.Forms.DLL /r:System.Drawing.DLL FirstForm.cs
```

However, I get errors like this:

```
FirstForm.cs(6,14): error CS0012: The type 'System.ComponentModel.Component' is
    defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference
    to assembly 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
    PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Windows.Forms.dll:
    (Location of symbol related to previous error)
```

I've already added "c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319" to my path. I don't know why it's telling me to reference it when I already have.

Comment: Why not use Visual Studio Express for this?

Comment: Yea, download it dude. Working with command line is a nightmare.

Comment: @Veech - jonnyGold is correct: "/r:System.dll" should help.  Oded and zgnilec are even *MORE* correct - you absolutely, totally, completely need to get a copy of MSVS.  For example, the free Visual Studio Express from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/express).

Comment: If you want to use a open source IDE, check out [Sharp Develop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/)

Comment: If you really want to code C#, you're probably going to be doing most of it on Microsoft.  Do yourself a favor, and get MSVS.  I would *not* mess around with MonoDevelop, SharpDevelop or anything besides Microsoft VS unless I had a very, very good reason.  IMHO...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add `/r:System.DLL` to your command line arguments